# Change Text on ASP.NET view depending on values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET view page that get's redirected by:

```
    public ActionResult Branch(string Branch)
    {
    var employees = from m in db.Employees
    where m.Branch == Branch || Branch == null || Branch == ""
    select m;
    return View(employees.ToList());
```

In my view is there a way to change h2 Branch /h2 depending on what branch is passed to the view page. Do if branch Tulsa is passed it displays Tulsa (h2 Tulsa /h2) or if Dallas is passed it would show ( h2 Dallas /h2 ) I guess maybe what I am asking how can I check what value is being passed as I want to dynamically display the address of that branch within the  h2 tag by what value is being passed. Make sense?

Here is where I want dynamic text: depending on the value of Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Branch)

```
    <h2>Dynamic Text Here</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="auto-style1">
                Branch
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Branch)
```

EB

Comment: Hi, please include the relevant .cshtml for your view page. Also, please format any code in your text (including HTML) using the code formatting tools.

Comment: OK. I added the view code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to your controller (I'm assuming the passed in argument is the Branch Name you want):

```
ViewBag.BranchName = Branch;
```

and change the H2 section in the view to be :

```
<h2>@ViewBag.BranchName</h2>
```

You can use either ViewData or ViewBag to pass additional data (in addition to the model) to the view.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!!